# Возврат с темной на светлую тему

Tags: дефект, поддержка, тёмная-тема

После возврата к светлой теме **исчезло выделение цветом текст**а (bold-ом?) ранее просмотренных вопросов на главной странице.

---

UPD-1

На другом компе (там я на темную тему не переходил) все как и раньше, цвет текста посещенного ранее вопроса немного темнее.

---

UPD-2

После перезагрузки эффект пропал

Comment: У меня цвет заголовка становится немного темнее.

Comment: @avp может кеши ???

Comment: @VictorVosMottor,  может быть (я не специалист в браузерах). Пока на темную опять не переключался. Может через некоторое время снова ее потестирую и тогда сообщу о результатах.